# How to add authentication to RECESS?

Tags: php, recess

I have a RECESS based project. I want to add password protection to the views where I add/edit/delete my new model objects, they should only be accessed after passing through a password entry view and if someone tries to access directly the said views should again get redirects to the login page. Any help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

1. create a class (authController) to handle the authentication connect to the database to query the user info
2. include the authController file in the main Application controller ie (MyRecessApp.class.php)
3. add the conditionals in your master.layout.php to check if the user is logged in and whether to render content or a login form
4. IMPORTANT: place the session_begin() that the authController needs in the recess-conf.php file.
5. Recommended: I ususally add the "loginUser" method to the User controller or you could have the User controller extend the authControllers methods